# Decrypt a file in C++ which has been encrypted with Node.JS Crypto

Tags: c++, node.js, encryption

I've been looking into a way to decrypt a file in c++ that's been encrypted using Node.js, I've tried a number of libraries and struggling to get the expected output.

Essentially, I'm encrypting the files using something similar to this example provided by http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/

```
// Nodejs encryption of buffers
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
    password = 'supersecretpassword1';

var fs = require('fs');

// input file
var r = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
// encrypt content
var encrypt = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
// write file
var w = fs.createWriteStream('file.out.txt');

// start pipe
r.pipe(encrypt).pipe(w);
```

So now it's encrypted, and can easily be decrypted in node using the password:

```
// decrypt content
var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password)
```

However, the requirement is to decrypt it using C++.

### Edit:

I've had go previously using https://github.com/ilvn/aes256ctr as it looks extremely lightweight and focuses on AES256-CTR (as used in the example above). However my assumption is it's just encrypting the data again instead of decrypting it:

```
#define aes256_decrypt_ctr  aes256_encrypt_ctr
```

Either that or potentially an issue with the encoding? As you can probably tell, encryption is fairly new to me.

Comment: what libraries have you tried?

Comment: libcrpto should be able to do it. It is for example used in openssl. The decryption method itself depends on the algorithm used. A simple one liner will probably not do. Do you know which algorithm was used in your case?

Comment: I've updated my question with a bit more info.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue Nico? I just posted a similar question except that I am using libgcrypt on c++ and decrypting a text string rather than a file